# React native rendering element but it is invisible

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I am working on a react native port of a react app. I am trying to use react-native-drag-sort to render some draggable elements

```
<AnySizeDragSortableView
    ref={sortableViewRef}
    dataSource={exampleData}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    onDataChange={(data, callback)=>{}}
    style={{height: "100%", width: "100%"}}
/>
```

```
function ExampleElement({text}) {
  console.log("Rendering " + text);
  return (
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', padding: 10, margin: 5,  zIndex:999}}>
      <Text style={{color: "#000000"}}>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

```
  function renderItem(item) {
    return (<ExampleElement text={item.text}/>)
  }
```

as you can see in the screenshots below, it *is* rendering them, and they have a size, but they are not visible. They have a z-index of 999 and a background color of red, so we should be able to see them.

Here is a screenshot of the debugger
[image: Debugger view]
And a screenshot of the app itself
[image: App view]

What could possibly be causing this behavior? The elements are clearly there in the debugger but are completely invisible. [Here is the full MRE source code](https://github.com/GNUGradyn/ReactNativeDragSortMre)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

By default, React Native elements use the relative positioning, which means that the z-index property may not work as expected.

Try explicitly setting the position property of the draggable elements to absolute in your ExampleElement component like this:

```
function ExampleElement({ text }) {
  console.log("Rendering " + text);
  return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', padding: 10, margin: 5, zIndex: 999, position: 'absolute' }}>
      <Text style={{ color: "#000000" }}>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work. The z-index thing was more of a hail mary anyway, there shouldn't be anything above or below it

Comment: This also causes all the invisible elements to be stacked on top of each other, as expected